# IPC pipe through files /dev/ttyS0 and /dev/ttyS1

Tags: c, linux, ipc, virtual-serial-port

I want to perform IPC pipe through serial port dev files. here are the requirements
first of all I am trying to use

```
sudo socat /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0,crnl /dev/ttyS1,raw,echo=0,crnl
```

it is giving an error as follows

```
2014/12/xx 10:33:19 socat[17848] E tcgetattr(4, 0x7fffe76ecaa0): Input/output error
```

Once the ttyS0 and ttyS1 are connected, I assume we can perform read/write operation as similar as using a pipe(), I will have two programs peer0.c and peer1.c, peer0.c opens /dev/ttyS0 and peer1.c opens /dev/ttyS1, 
so that read write operation should be as follows

```
peer0=>ttyS0--->---ttyS1=>peer1
peer0<=ttyS0---<---ttyS1<=peer1
```

and since /dev/ttyS(0/1) are system wide, i can run peer0.c program in one terminal and peer1.c in another,

Basically, I have linux based embedded application program which when ported to target hardware it will be controlled by linux based PC via minicom UART interface. target opens its ttyS0 to read uart data sent from PC, in PC, commands will be sent to target via minicom.
Now I want to run target application in same PC in one terminal and want to send command from another terminal/minicom. Also the communication should be bidirectional

is it possible to achieve this goal?
or is there any other similar way to achieve the same?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just transfer files, use a protocol for doing so over serial links, such as ZMODEM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM), if you want full IPC, establish a PPP connection over the link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> peer0=>ttyS0--->---ttyS1=>peer1
> peer0<=ttyS0---<---ttyS1<=peer1
> ```

You seem to want `socat` to take the part of the `--->---` and `---<---` above. This is not possible, because `socat` had to open `ttyS0` and `ttyS1` and compete with `peer0` for input from `ttyS0` as well as with `peer1` for input from `ttyS1`.
To achieve the goal of communicating with an application on one serial port via another port, just connect the two ports with a null modem cable.